# How can I profile pure dll?

Tags: c++, python, dll, profiling

I have project that creates dlls. These dlls are invoked from python later by special plugin system blue-sky. So in this project it's very hard to build executable file, but I need profiling. Are there any profilers that can work with pure dlls?

I've tried Intel Amplifier, Microsoft VS2008 profiler they don't work. I've also tried Very Sleepy but its features are limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dll is loaded by Python then you need to profile the Python process.  With the Microsoft profiler as long as all the .pdb files are present it should resolve symbols within the dll.  Another option is to create an executable that loads and calls the functions you're interested in and then profile said executable.

E.g. You may have a "python.exe" process that is running your python program which is loading the .dll and you can attach the visual studio command line profiler to it by:

> vsperfcmd /attach:"python.exe"

Answer (score 1):

You can't profile code that isn't running- that's the definition of profiling. You will need to build something that can run (an executable file) that links to the DLL and use that.

Comment: Actually code from these dll is running so there is possibility to profile, isn't there? Build something that links to the DLLs is very difficult, because then I'll have to rewrite all plugins loader system from python to C/C++.

Comment: It's not very hard, actually. The OS is in control of DLL loading. When Windows loads your DLL, it will check for dependencies and load those too. Just pass the DLL you want loaded to the linker. You don't even need to call a function from that DLL; Windows will still call its `DllMain()`.

Comment: It's not so simple. DLLs should be loaded in certain order becouse they export their types to this system. I don't want to go in details but it really isn't simple. If you're interested you can check: http://sourceforge.net/projects/blue-sky/